# Need help printing list

Tags: python, zsh

I'm working on a todo list in Python and I am currently stuck on printing the todo list.

I have my add code and view code as such:

```
if sel == '1': #add task        
     name = input("enter task name: ")
     prio = input("enter priority level (High | Medium | Low): ")
     add(todo, name, prio)
     view(task)
elif sel == '3': #print todo list
     view2(task)
     exit
```

and these are the functions im using:

```
def add(todo, x, y):
    todo[x] = y

def view(x):
    x.append(dict(todo))

def view2(x):
    print(x)
```

I'm able to add items to a dictionary print the dictionary the first time i select the option to print list. The second time i print it gives the below output

```
[{'test 1': 'low'}, {'test 1': 'low', 'test 2 ': 'low'}]
```

my ultimate goal is to get an output as shown below, but i can't get passed this first wall. Any advice? also, would i need to print a nested dictionary to get a numbered list?

```
1 - test 1 - low
2 - test 2 - low
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is this what your list looks like? ```[{'test 1': 'low'}, {'test 2 ': 'low'}]```

Comment: What are you asking for here?  Are you asking why your sample output doesn't match in content what you want, or are you asking about the formatting of the output?  Is it the duplicated "test 1" that's bothering you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming view2(x) is the function for printing and x is the dictionary which you have mentioned in the question.

You can do something like this

```
def view2(x):
    for key, val in x.items():
        print("{0} - {1}".format(key, val))
```

Comment: This solved it ! Do you know how i can number my list?  right now it prints like below
test 1 - high
test 2 - med
test 3 - low

but i want it to print like 
1 - test 1 - high
2 - test 2 - med
3 - test 3 - low

Comment: Hmm, the easiest way is to have a counter, Increment the counter in the for loop and use the counter in print statement `print("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(counter,key, val))`

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for any number of todos in the list.

```
todo_list = [{'test 1': 'low'}, {'test 2': 'low'}]
def show(todo_list):
    for index, todo in enumerate(todo_list, start=1):
        for key in todo.keys(): 
            print(index, key, todo[key])

show(todo_list)
```

Comment: IfIf i use this method it does cause the numbers to repeat as such
1 test 1 high
2 test 1 high
2 test 2 med
3 test 1 high
3 test 2 med
3 test 3 low

Comment: What is repeating?

Comment: it essential repeats the list of items when a new item is entered into the todo list. So if i only enter 1 item at first and print it prints the first item. then if i enter a second item it then print item 1, then print item 1 & 2. it continues this pattern the more items you add to the todo list.