# Display numbered list

Tags: python, zsh

My last question was solved, but I'm now needing a bit more to be printed. my below code currently prints the below.

Input

```
# Add task to list
def add(todo, x, y):
    todo[x] = y

# View task
def view2(x):
    for key, val in x.items():
        print("{0} - {1}".format(key, val))

if sel == '1': #add task
            name = input("Please provide a task name: ")
            prio = input("Please select prioty level (High | Medium | Low): ")
            add(todo, name, prio)
            exit

elif sel == '3': #print todo list
            view2(todo)
            exit
```

output

```
test 1 - high 
test 2 - med 
test 3 - low
```

but I need the below output

```
1 - test 1 - high 
2 - test 2 - med 
3 - test 3 - low
```

The next piece of code will take the number of the list item and delete the item from the list, which is why i require a numbered list as shown above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help printing list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872369/need-help-printing-list)

Comment: Could you please post code in a manner that people can get to the issue right away. The code above doesn't show the output you mentioned.. so will need a lot of effort in recreating the issue.

Comment: @MK212test : Why is this tagged _zsh_? There is no Zsh code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be like

```py
# View task
def view2(x):
    n_order = 0
    for key, val in x.items():
        n_order += 1
        print("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(n_order, key, val))
```

Answer (score 1):

***Remove Item From List***

This done by selecting `sel` as `2`.

1. Translate task number to index
2. Validate task index is valid
3. Remove item from list by index using [del](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)

```
def remove(todo, number):
    index = number - 1
    if not(0 < index < len(todo)):
        print('Invalid task number')
    else:
        del todo[index]
```

***View Task List***

[Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) over the `todo_list`, this would let you both know the current task index and it's value:

```
# View task
def view2(todo_list):
    for index, todo in enumerate(todo_list, start=1):
        for key in todo.keys():
            print(f'{index} - {key} - {todo[key]}')
```

***Full Code***

```
# Add task to list
def add(todo, x, y):
    todo[x] = y

def remove(todo, number):
    index = number - 1
    if not(0 < index < len(todo)):
        print('Invalid task number')
    else:
        del todo[index]

# View task
def view2(todo_list):
    for index, todo in enumerate(todo_list, start=1):
        for key in todo.keys():
            print(f'{index} - {key} - {todo[key]}')

todo = [{'test 1': 'high'}, {'test 2': 'med'}, {'test 3': 'low'}]


while True:
    sel = input("Please enter command (1=Add, 2=Delete, 3=View): \n")

    if sel == '1': #add task
                name = input("Please provide a task name: ")
                prio = input("Please select prioty level (High | Medium | Low): ")
                add(todo, name, prio)

    elif sel == '2':
        number = int(input("Please provide a task number: "))
        remove(todo, number)

    elif sel == '3': #print todo list
                view2(todo)
    else:
        break
```

Output:

```
Please enter command (1=Add, 2=Delete, 3=View): 
3
1 - test 1 - high
2 - test 2 - med
3 - test 3 - low
Please enter command (1=Add, 2=Delete, 3=View): 
2
Please provide a task number: 2
Please enter command (1=Add, 2=Delete, 3=View): 
3
1 - test 1 - high
2 - test 3 - low
```